# Can't redefine \val from polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

At some recent package update (not sure which one), polyglossia seems to define `\val` to contain the value given to the `variant` key.

In one of my documents I have defined `\val`, which I don't want to rename because I used it several times in my document. But polyglossia override my definition of `\val`. I tried with `\AtBeginDocument` but this doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\show\val

\AtBeginDocument{
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\val}{}{some new definition} % Does not work
}
\begin{document}
    \val % prints british
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need `\AfterEndPreamble`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That worked. Care to write that as an answer?

Comment: The problem is in the usage of `xkeyval`. I'll open an issue.

Comment: See https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/390. Every time a choice key is evaluated, `\val` and `\nr` are redefined. So doing the definition of `\val` at begin document is not really safe.

Comment: On the other hand, it's quite likely that the issue will appear again whenever a package using choice keys from `xkeyval` is loaded and a choice is performed, because of bad documentation of the package that leads people to think that `\val\nr` is mandatory usage.

Comment: sorry I hadn't the time to check if something in the document could overwrite the command again but I see @egreg took care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a tough situation, which stems from history.

The few examples in the documentation of `xkeyval` for `\define@choicekey` all use `[\val\nr]` and this has instilled the idea that these are mandatory tokens for this case.

They aren't. Any two control sequences are allowed and they are used as scratch macros. Package writers should use their own control sequences; so the example in the documentation

```latex
\define@choicekey*{fam}{align}[\val\nr]{left,center,right}{%
  \ifcase\nr\relax
    \raggedright
  \or
    \centering
  \or
    \raggedleft
  \fi
}
```

adapted to the package `foo` should better be

```latex
\define@choicekey*{fam}{align}[\foo@val\foo@nr]{left,center,right}{%
  \ifcase\foo@nr\relax
    \raggedright
  \or
    \centering
  \or
    \raggedleft
  \fi
}
```

and the code in the `polyglossia` definition files should be

```latex
\define@choicekey*+{welsh}{date}[\xpg@val\xpg@nr]{long,short}[short]{%
   \ifcase\xpg@nr\relax
      % long:
      \welsh@formaldatetrue
   \or
      % accented:
      \welsh@formaldatefalse
   \fi
   \xpg@info{Option: Welsh, date=\xpg@val}%
}{\xpg@warning{Unknown date value `#1'}}
```

Unfortunately, most packages or classes using `xkeyval` and choice keys adopted `\var\nr`. These scratch control sequences are *not* set inside a group, so any time one performs a choice key using them they are redefined and their final value is unpredictable.

What can you do? Avoid `\val` as the name of a personal macro.

I filed a issue report for `polyglossia` and I'll do what's possible to inform authors of other packages. But it will take long until the situation improves.

Comment: uff. I'm using `[\@tempval\@tempnr]` in chessboard - which isn't completly perfect but not too bad either ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're among the few who understood the package, I guess.

Comment: I probably simply had the healthy idea not to use document commands and so tried it. But I'm not quite sure about the numbers - I can see quite a number of packages using \val\nr (among these datatools and \datetime) but finding the packages avoiding it is a bit more challeging.